# Highchart x-axis show label after specific days no matter what is in the x-axis categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my code for highchart:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

$('#container-chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        alignTicks: false,
    },
    title: {
        text: "Title 1",
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y',new Date(this.x))+ '<br/>' + this.y;
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [1391122800000,1393542000000,1396216800000,1398808800000,1401487200000,1404079200000,1406757600000,1409436000000,1412028000000,1414710000000,1417302000000,1419980400000,1422658800000,1425078000000,1427752800000,1430344800000,1433023200000,1435615200000,1438293600000,1440972000000,1443564000000,1446246000000,1448838000000,1451516400000,1454194800000,1456700400000,1459375200000,1461967200000,1464645600000,1467237600000,1469916000000,1472594400000,1475186400000,1477868400000,1480460400000,1483138800000,1485817200000,1488236400000,1490911200000,1493503200000,1496181600000,1498773600000,1501452000000,1504130400000,1506722400000,1509404400000,1511996400000,1514674800000,1517353200000,1519772400000,1522447200000,1525039200000,1527717600000,1530309600000,1532988000000,1535666400000,1538258400000,1540940400000],
        // tickInterval: (24 * 3600 * 1000 * 173),
        labels: {
            formatter: function () { 
                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %y", this.value);
            },
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: ''
        },
    },
    legend: {
        enable: true,
    },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    allowOverlap: true,
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0.57,0.41,0.51,0.35,0.16,0.16,0.05,0.19,0.27,0.57,0.45,0.59,0.49,0.77,0.56,0.25,0.3,0.28,0.27,0.33,0.45,0.62,0.62,0.46,0.46,0.45,0.68,0.18,0.22,0.28,0.29,0.41,0.34,0.59,0.67,0.69,0.65,0.57,0.73,-0.01,0.32,0.27,0.47,0.47,0.57,0.75,0.7,0.6,0.71,0.88,0.79,-0.11,0.22,0.15,0.07,0.09,0.09,0.09],
        }],
        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 1500
        },

});
```

I have 58 days data for highchart's xAxis categories properties. The date difference from 1st day data to 58th date data is 1734 i.e. total number of days are 1734 days. Now, Say, i only want to show 10 labels on x-axis, of equal distance including first and last data, that means, label interval will be 173 days. How can i achieve this label interval no matter what date gap present in x-axis categories ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tickPositioner` function, but you should use timestamps as x values not as categories:

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var positions = [],
            interval = 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 173;

        for (var i = this.dataMin; i <= this.dataMax; i += interval) {
            positions.push(i);
        }

        return positions;
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %y", this.value);
        },
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/npq3x2bc/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 0):

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

$('#container-chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        alignTicks: false,
    },
    title: {
        text: "Title 1",
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y',new Date(this.x))+ '<br/>' + this.y;
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [1391122800000,1393542000000,1396216800000,1398808800000,1401487200000,1404079200000,1406757600000,1409436000000,1412028000000,1414710000000,1417302000000,1419980400000,1422658800000,1425078000000,1427752800000,1430344800000,1433023200000,1435615200000,1438293600000,1440972000000,1443564000000,1446246000000,1448838000000,1451516400000,1454194800000,1456700400000,1459375200000,1461967200000,1464645600000,1467237600000,1469916000000,1472594400000,1475186400000,1477868400000,1480460400000,1483138800000,1485817200000,1488236400000,1490911200000,1493503200000,1496181600000,1498773600000,1501452000000,1504130400000,1506722400000,1509404400000,1511996400000,1514674800000,1517353200000,1519772400000,1522447200000,1525039200000,1527717600000,1530309600000,1532988000000,1535666400000,1538258400000,1540940400000],
        // tickInterval: (24 * 3600 * 1000 * 173),
        labels: {
            formatter: function () { 
                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %y", this.value);
            },
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: ''
        },
         tickInterval:(maxValue/10),
            min: 0,
            max: maxValue,
    },
    legend: {
        enable: true,
    },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    allowOverlap: true,
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0.57,0.41,0.51,0.35,0.16,0.16,0.05,0.19,0.27,0.57,0.45,0.59,0.49,0.77,0.56,0.25,0.3,0.28,0.27,0.33,0.45,0.62,0.62,0.46,0.46,0.45,0.68,0.18,0.22,0.28,0.29,0.41,0.34,0.59,0.67,0.69,0.65,0.57,0.73,-0.01,0.32,0.27,0.47,0.47,0.57,0.75,0.7,0.6,0.71,0.88,0.79,-0.11,0.22,0.15,0.07,0.09,0.09,0.09],
        }],
        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 1500
        },

});
```

here I have added :
tickInterval:(maxValue/10),
            min: 0,
            max: maxValue,

it means you need to fist get max value and take the nearest value divisible by 10 and use , I hope it will help you

Comment: I want 173 days interval for x-axis, not y-axis @MKJ

Comment: use the same tickInterval for x-axis and devide max value by how many interval you need. @NazemMahmud

for more you can refer :  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval